# How to make amazing button in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to make a button as the below.
Please help me.
[image]

Comment: Is there going to be text on the button or any specific kinds of gesture interactions with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it:

This one uses `skewX`:

```
<View style={{
  width: 200,
  height: 50,
  borderWidth: 4,
  borderColor: 'black',
  // Uncomment this to see how it looks unclipped
  overflow: 'hidden',
  borderRadius: 10,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  position: 'relative',
  // These are to center the text
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}}>
  <View style={{
    width: 120,
    height: 70,
    position: 'absolute',
    // These offsets were required because the transform
    // would move them off the edges
    right: -10,
    top: -10,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    borderLeftWidth: 5,
    borderLeftColor: 'black',
    transform: [{
      skewX: '-45deg',
    }]
  }} />
  <Text style={{
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    fontSize: 20,
  }}>Hello World</Text>
</View>
```

And here's the other way using `rotateX`:

```
<View style={{
  width: 200,
  height: 50,
  borderWidth: 4,
  borderColor: 'black',
  // Uncomment this to see how it looks unclipped
  overflow: 'hidden',
  borderRadius: 10,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  position: 'relative',
  // These are to center the text
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}}>
  <View style={{
    width: 100,
    height: 150,
    position: 'absolute',
    // These offsets were required because the transform
    // would move them off the edges
    right: 10,
    top: -30,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    borderLeftWidth: 4,
    borderLeftColor: 'black',
    transform: [{
      rotate: '45deg',
    }]
  }} />
  <Text style={{
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    fontSize: 20,
  }}>Hello World</Text>
</View>
```

I prefer the rotation method because the skew will mess with the border width of the diagonal line.